# Entry Cursor not appearing when set in button's clicked event handler Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, cursor-position

I have an entry that's IsVisible property is set to false. Then I have a button that has a clicked event handler that sets the entry IsVisible to true and sets the focus and cursor position of the entry. The entry_focused event handler is fired, but there is no focus /cursor on the entry and no keyboard appears.

Here is the Button_Clicked event handler:

```
 void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     //doesn't show cursor
     AmntEntry.IsVisible = true;
     AmntEntry.Focus();
     AmntEntry.CursorPosition = 2;
 }
```

Please let me know how to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: Testing on Android, iOS, or UWP? Does it work if the xaml that creates AmntEntry has `IsVisible="True"`? (I understand that isn't what you want, but I want to know whether it works if the Entry starts out visible.)

Comment: I have tested the code you provided with Entry which set the `IsVisible` property to false.  After clicking the button, the cursor and keyboard display well on Android. Could you provide more details for me to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am testing this on an ios simulator, and yes if I set IsVisible="True" in xaml, it does work.

Comment: So what could I help you with now？

Comment: I ended up just using a different control to achieve my goal. Thanks for your help.